# AJAX TruClient protocol takes more time to load a page

Tags: jquery, web-applications, protocols, loadrunner, truclient

I have recorded my application using Ajax TruClient protocol, when recording noticed that it took more time to load each and every page when compared to HTTP/HTML.  On manually launching the jsp page, it takes less than 3 sec to load but Ajax TruClient script is taking more than 21 seconds to load the same jsp page. I have tried changing all the run time settings, but this protocol is taking more than the expected time to load the page.

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Thanks
John

Comment: Could you please provide more details on the LR version TruClient type (IE or Firefox). And it would help if you could post a link to something we can check this on.

Answer (score 1):

**Check the number of resources being downloaded**

Using the HTTP/HTML protocol you will only count the page elements (extraes) that you have included in your script / found by LoadRunner. This is often a lot less than would be found by the actual browser. Open up the site in something like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and see what the actual page load time is there first.

**AJAX TruClient "end" transaction times sometimes need attention**

When ending a timing point in AJAX TruClient there are 5 options:

- Action Completed
- Step Network Completed
- DOM Content Loaded
- Document Loaded
- Dialog Opened

You may need to change the end transaction 'End Event' to suit your particular site.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that Joel said, plus ...

> > "*I have recorded my application using Ajax TruClient protocol, when recording noticed that it took more time to load each and every page when compared to HTTP/HTML. On manually launching the jsp page, it takes less than 3 sec to load but Ajax TruClient script is taking more than 21 seconds ...*"

Just to be clear, the Web/http protocol is only pulling the info from the server, it is *not* attempting to render the page or run any client-side JavaScript. The TruClient scripts are most likely doing this unless you change the end events as described above.